# Show UIKeyboard in another position iOS, iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, sdk, uikeyboard

i have a question, how to show keyboard on iPad but upper on 50 pixels ? I want to my tabbar stay visible even keyboard shows. Thx.

Comment: Bad idea. Strongly recommend you to reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

I just read it and found something interesting.[**This**](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6275-add-toolbar-top-keyboard.html) might be helpful to you.